# Children screaming and crying while sleeping

Tags: sleep

I am a working woman and a single mother. The last few days my child has become distressed while sleeping; she is 6 years old.

She will start crying out as if in pain at night and though I always try to stop her, she doesn't respond and continues being in distress.

Most often she's grinding her teeth. I am very upset by the and need help to resolve this issue as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

My son used to do this, supposedly they are common with younger children. Night terrors are what they call them. My son gradually stopped when in the morning I would ask him what he dreamed, sometimes he remembered and sometimes no. I would explain to him that each thing was not real and that he was safe. I also cut out all cartoons with violence for a long long time all he watched was Thomas and veggie tales, he stopped having the night terrors. Good luck, I know its hard and it can be frustrating trying to console a screaming child awake or no, I used to carry mine for hours outside and around the house until they realized it was only a dream. Best of luck, I assure you it will get better.